# Group dictionary values together based on a key

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I am looking to group values in an input set together with the first element in a tuple acting as the key. The second elements need to be grouped together to a list based on the common key. Output needs to be a list with tuples.

```
# Input set
values = {(304008, 2020.0), (304008, 2017.0), (250128, 2020.0), (93646, 2020.0), (93646, 2017.0)}

# Current workflow
keys = {i[0] for i in values}

id_dict = dict()
for k in keys:
    id_dict[k] = [int(i[1]) for i in values if i[0] == k]

lst2 = list(id_dict.items())
# Expected output
# [(250128, [2020]), (304008, [2017, 2020]), (93646, [2020, 2017])]
```

I have the expected output, but the whole process is too slow. I am looking to make it faster. I was looking at groupby functions, but I can't seem to make them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to accomplish this. Basically groupby the first element in the tuple, then make a list of the second elements in each group.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [(k, [i[1] for i in g]) for k, g in groupby(sorted(values), key=lambda i: i[0])]
[(93646, [2017.0, 2020.0]), (250128, [2020.0]), (304008, [2017.0, 2020.0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setdefault to make a dict with key as first item of tuple and iterate on the set to populate it in single shot.
The use list constructor to get the required list. See below:

```
>>> values = {(304008, 2020.0), (304008, 2017.0), (250128, 2020.0), (93646, 2020.0), (93646, 2017.0)}
>>> info = {}
>>> for elements in values:
...     info.setdefault(elements[0], []).append(elements[1])
... 
>>> list(info.items())
[(304008, [2017.0, 2020.0]), (93646, [2017.0, 2020.0]), (250128, [2020.0])]
>>>
```

This does not use groupby but avoids your second loop.